# Failed to resolve dependencies in my app

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to add a library to my project.
This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "XXXXX"
            password "XXXXX"
        }
        url "https://developers.interpay.se/nexus/content/repositories/Interpay/"
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "interpay.XXX.XXX.com.interpay"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'se.interpay:terminal:0.7.7'
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Error:(38, 13) Failed to resolve: se.interpay:terminal:0.7.7  
<a href="openFile:D:/XXXX/XXXX/Interpay/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br>  
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: refer : https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/1267aeb83a97db4875f496afa70616dc

Comment: I have seen this page before, did not help

Comment: (From Review:) I add some formatting to your question and added a tag.

Comment: Which part of the error doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer ..
I have to update android studio to work with the new maven version in hosting website